# HTTP400 Bad Request when attempting to upload file via AJAX post to .NET controller

Tags: .net, ajax, api, file, upload

I am receiving this error when attempting to upload any file that is not a .txt file. Text files are working properly. I am assuming this issue was not happening one year ago as this code went through multiple testing phases and it would have been easily found that all files besides .txt cannot be uploaded. The server code is VB.net:

ajax:

```
            var uFile = new FormData();
            var files = $(careerInformationSession.dg).find("#CareerSessionModel_Document_UploadFile").get(0).files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                uFile.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
                var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: careerInformationSession.api + "UploadFile",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: uFile,
                    success: function (data) {
                        careerInformationSession.uploadSuccess(data);
                    },
                    error: function (ts) {
                        careerInformationSession.callFailure();
                    }
                });
```

server:

```
    <System.Web.Http.HttpPost> 
    Public Function UploadFile() As String
        Dim returnValue As String = String.Empty
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any() Then
            ' Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
            Dim httpPostedFile As System.Web.HttpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("UploadedImage")
            If httpPostedFile IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim validateFile As New ValidateAjaxPostedFile(5120, "JPG,PNG,PDF,JPEG,GIF", httpPostedFile)
                If validateFile.Validate() Then
                    SessionManager.SetSessionData(CWDS.Framework.Utilities.SessionManager.SubSystem.EM, CAREER_INFO_SESSION_FILE, validateFile.FileData)
                    SessionManager.SetSessionData(CWDS.Framework.Utilities.SessionManager.SubSystem.EM, CAREER_INFO_SESSION_FILE_NAME, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(httpPostedFile.FileName))
                Else
                    Return returnValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return returnValue
    End Function
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the issue, but may only have a temporary fix. We are calling InvokeIsValidRequestString to prevent scripts from being inserted in api calls. This .net function was flagging any non text file as malicious for an unknown reason.

Original code:

Return (New CustomRequestValidation).InvokeIsValidRequestString(HttpContext.Current, (New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)).ReadToEnd().Replace(",", ","), RequestValidationSource.Form, Nothing, -1)

New code:

If HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return (New CustomRequestValidation).InvokeIsValidRequestString(HttpContext.Current, (New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)).ReadToEnd().Replace(",", ","), RequestValidationSource.Form, Nothing, -1)
            End If

Our new code works as we still have a virus scanner that is run after these initial steps.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to validate ajax/json requests. I extended RequestValidator but it is not exposing "InvokeIsValidRequestString" function. I found lots of people using this function in C# but only you in VB. Could you post the "CustomRequestValidation" class? Maybe I could see what I am doing wrong. Thank you